Graphql or rest in RT chat in a spa running on flask and react?
I have a react app using flask backend. I have changed from rest to grapgql now for user reg, login, auto. Also posting services and for the feed to GET the posts. I am going to implement a one-to-one real time chat and was wondering: grapgql or rest. Also ws run on same flask app, good idea?
I’m developing it for the time being. I have done something similar before with rest and MySQL but not real time. I want to  make it real time but still log the chat.
